# Using Drop Down list with Odata, Knockout JS and HTML 5 in asp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC 4 internet application in which I have several fields on a html table through which I pull up the data from the database and display, edit and delete it from the UI using OData and Knockout JavaScript.

Earlier I used normal text boxes for editing the records on the webpage and it worked as t should but now for some reasons I changed the text boxes to drop down list for term field which has some list of terms that is pulled from the database. I was able to pull the data and display it in the drop down list but was not able to update the from the UI whenever I edit the row using drop down list.

I have the following code which enables me to pull data from databse and put it on the web page.

**Knockout JavaScript**

```
var CanadianCrudeViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
 self.terms = ko.observableArray();
 self.termNames = ko.observable();

self.selectedTerm = ko.observable();

    self.add = function (canadiancrude) {
        var payload = {
            Term: this.selectedTerm() , Product: "Product", Location: "Location", Pipeline: "Pipeline",
            BidCP: "Bid CP", BidVolume: "Bid Volume", Index: "Index", Bid: "0.0", Offer: "0.0",
            OfferVolume: "Offer Volume", OfferCP: "Offer CP"
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes',
            type: 'POST',
            //  data: ko.toJSON(payload),
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }


 self.watchModel = function (model, callback) {
        for (var key in model) {
            if (model.hasOwnProperty(key) && ko.isObservable(model[key]) && key !== 'Locked' && key != 'Edit') {
                self.subscribeToProperty(model, key, function (key, val) {
                    callback(model, key, val);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    self.subscribeToProperty = function (model, key, callback) {
        model[key].subscribe(function (val) {
            callback(key, val);
        });
    }

    self.modelChanged = function (model, key, val) {
        var payload = {};
        payload[key] = val;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes(' + model.Id + ')',
            type: 'PATCH',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }



    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/odata/Terms',
        data: ko.toJSON(self.termNames),
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            self.termNames((ko.utils.arrayMap(data.value, function (term) {
                var obsCanadianCrudeTermName = {
                    Id: term.Id,
                    TermName: term.TermName,
                    Locked: ko.observable(term.Locked),
                }
                self.watchModel(obsCanadianCrudeTermName, self.modelChanged);
                return obsCanadianCrudeTermName;
            })));
        }
    });


 $.getJSON('/odata/Terms', function (termdata) {

        self.canadiancrudes(ko.utils.arrayMap(termdata.value, function (term) {
            var obsCanadianCrude = {
                Id: term.Id,

                TermName: term.TermName,

                Edit: ko.observable(false),
                Locked: ko.observable(term.Locked),
            }
            self.watchModel(obsCanadianCrude, self.modelChanged);
            return obsCanadianCrude;
        }))
    });

$(function () {

    var viewModel = new CanadianCrudeViewModel();
 viewModel.terms.push(obsCanadianCrude);

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

**HTML TABLE**

```
<script type="text/html" id="edit-template">




    <td>
        @*<input type="text" id="txbQuarter" data-bind="value: Term" />*@
      <select data-bind="options: $root.termNames, optionsText: 'TermName', optionsValue: 'TermName',value: Term,optionsCaption: 'Choose a Term'">
           </select>
        </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txbLocation" data-bind="value: Location" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txbPipeline" data-bind="value: Pipeline" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txbBidCP" data-bind="value: BidCP" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txbIndex" data-bind="value: Index" /></td>

    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txbBidVolume" data-bind="value: BidVolume" /></td>

    <td class="ticker">


        <input type="text" id="txbBid" data-bind="value: Bid" />


    </td>

    <td class="ticker">

        <input type="text" id="txbOffer" data-bind="value: Offer" />

    </td>



    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txbOfferVolume" data-bind="value: OfferVolume" /></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txbOfferCP" data-bind="value: OfferCP" /></td>
    <td class="actioncells"></td>
    <td class="actioncells">


        <a class="btn btn-success" title="Save Changes" data-bind="click: $root.done">Done</a>

    </td>

    <td></td>

</script>
```

**COntroller**

```
private WhiteBoardAppContext db = new WhiteBoardAppContext();
        [Queryable(AllowedQueryOptions = System.Web.Http.OData.Query.AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
        public override IQueryable<Term> Get()
        {
            return db.Terms;
        }

        protected override Term GetEntityByKey(int key)
        {
            return db.Terms.Find(key);
        }

        protected override int GetKey(Term entity)
        {
            return entity.Id;
        }

        protected override Term PatchEntity(int key, Delta<Term> patch)
        {
            Term termToPatch = db.Terms.Find(key);
            patch.Patch(termToPatch);
            db.Entry(termToPatch).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            var changedProperty = patch.GetChangedPropertyNames().ToList()[0];
            object changedPropertyValue;
            patch.TryGetPropertyValue(changedProperty, out changedPropertyValue);

            Hub.Clients.All.updatedTerm(termToPatch.Id, changedProperty, changedPropertyValue);

            return termToPatch;
        }

        protected override Term UpdateEntity(int key, Term update)
        {
            return base.UpdateEntity(key, update);
        }


        protected override Term CreateEntity(Term entity)
        {
            var newTerm = db.Terms.Find(entity.Id);
            if (newTerm == null)
            {
                newTerm = db.Terms.Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                newTerm = db.Terms.Add(newTerm);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            Hub.Clients.All.addTerm(newTerm);
            return newTerm;
        }

        public override void Delete(int key)
        {
            var termToDelete = db.Terms.Find(key);
            db.Terms.Remove(termToDelete);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Hub.Clients.All.removeTerm(key);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }
```

In the above HTML I have a line commented which the previous version when I used normal text box for editing which worked fine without any issue.

May I know a better way I could fix this ?

Comment: I can admit I haven't really read everything thouroughly, but shouldn't you also use the <code>value:Term</code> binding on the select element?

Comment: I have already binded data to select statement, what I really want is to insert data into the database using the data binded in the drop down list.

Comment: Without using the `value:selectedTerm` binding, how would you know which item has been selected?

Comment: That was my mistake, I was using it before but didn't work, I have edited the question

Comment: Sorry, I found it I am binding the selected value to the wrong field, I have edit my question and its working. Thanks for noting me regarding the value :)